# Why class fields is not overriden

Tags: java, c#, oop

I know that in Java and C# classes the fields is not overren (but the methods do). I know that fact, but I don't understand what is the reason in such implementation. It is not predictable and obvious. Why do we have such implementation of OOP ?

```
public class Flight {
    int seats = 150;
}

public class CargoFlight  extends Flight {
    int seats = 12;
}

CargoFlight f1 = new CargoFlight();
System.out.println(f1.seats);

Flight f2 = new CargoFlight();
System.out.println(f2.seats);
```

And:

```
class Flight
{
    public int Seats = 150;      
}

class CargoFlight : Flight
{
    public int Seats = 20;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CargoFlight f1 = new CargoFlight();
        Console.WriteLine(f1.Seats);

        Flight f2 = new CargoFlight();
        Console.WriteLine(f2.Seats);            

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Overriding is intended for specializing *behaviour*, not *state*. It would be weird to be declaring two variables separately but only ending up with one piece of state, IMO. What you're really looking for is an *assignment* to the existing state, and that's easily achieved.

Comment: how is this overriding?? you are just assigning new values.....we generally override behaviors because many times we want diff behavior for derived class...you can associate behaviors to methods in class...

Comment: 'just assigning new values' - that's not what you're doing. You're *declaring* 2 different fields, one shadows the other. If you want, you can assign a new value. There's nothing to stop that.

Comment: overriding would be when you change the data type itself of that variable.....just imagine Base class has string variable and string manipulation method and you override it to change it to Int and call that base method.....does it make any sense?? no right...thats why OOP does not have such implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned that these languages are OOP based and OOP is very much influenced by real world concepts. From a real world example: If a child inherits something from his/her parent, he/she inherits state of parent (property, wealth etc which he/she can not override by adding more wealth) but he/she can override their parent's behavior (how he/she speaks, walks, understands etc).

Similarly, in programming when a class inherits, it inherits both state and behavior from parent. But it can not override parent's state arbitrarily, though it can use it. And child class has liberty to override parent's behavior (methods).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in that format, it can look really disorientating, but thinking how the language works helps a bit.

For example most of the time we assign class-specific toString-method despite we could just as happily use the one the parent class Object (the one that rules them all!) has defined to us. However most of the time Object's toString-method doesn't really suit on our purposes and we write different sort of toString-method that suits far better for our class.

While this isn't shown in code such clearly as it does in your examples, it's how the whole language works, actually; subclasses inherit the parent classes methods and if it doesn't really work for them the way intended, they are overridden to suit better for the purposes of the class. It's much more clearer IMO in classes we are writing ourselves than when we are using excisting classes.

Of course you could try to plan your classes the way you don't need to override your own classes, but it's much more efficient to let the parent class define some generic methods and then define them more specific if/when needed.